# Convenience method(s) for setting OpenCL kernel arguments?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, opencl, convenience-methods

It seems to me that a lot of the OpenCL kernel argument setting can be streamlined. The most rudimentary thing one can think of is implementing:

```
clSetKernelArgs(cl_kernel kernel, unsigned num_args, ...)
```

and then for each argument can one can read either a triplet of arg_index, arg_size and value, or a pair of arg_size and arg_value, or even just the argument (if one could somehow figure out within the impl what the signature types are).

Isn't this already implemented somewhere as part of the standard?

**Note:** I'm interested both in C and C++ code.

Comment: The question is tagged c++ so I assume your code is in C++. Then I strongly suggest you look at the C++ Bindings (and their specification: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/). They make things a hell of a lot easier!

Comment: @MatthiasHolzapfel: Will look into it; but I'm also interested in C code for this, since I'm not sure I'll be able to only write C++ code.

Comment: As far as I know there's nothing in the C standard. For anyone looking for an implementation similar to what was described, I have a simple utility function that I use for this: http://pastebin.com/Enamp0EF. Use at your own risk.